# Xamarin Studio vs Visual Studio Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ide, development-environment

Any really goods reasons and/or things to be aware of why one should use Xamarin Studio over Visual Studio for Xamarin projects (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Xamarin Studio is no longer supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since the support for XS on Windows was dropped and the same will eventually happen to XS for Mac. Visual Studio will become the only IDE for both Mac and Windows to develop Xamarin Apps.

For me this is the best reason to start using Visual Studio.